# Trying to Import data into SQL Server from Access

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I tried this small script below.

```
USE [Test]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Import_From_Access]    Script Date: 4/16/2017 5:13:19 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Import_From_Access]
AS
BEGIN


SET NOCOUNT ON;

EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
@server = 'EXCEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS',
@provider = 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
@srvproduct = 'OLE DB Provider for Jet',
@datasrc = 'C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Coding\Microsoft Access\Northwind.mdb'

EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'EXCEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS', FALSE, Null, Admin, Null

END
```

Then, to run it, i tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY('EXCEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS', 'SELECT * FROM Table1')
```

Now, I thought that would work, but I'm getting an error message that reads:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 'EXCEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS'.

I am thinking that the issue may be the '-' character or the '\' character.  unfortunately, that is the name of the server machine, and it's probably not going to change.  If there a work-around for this kind of thing, or am I just out of luck with this kind of setup?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXCEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS` isn't a string literal:

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY([EXCEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS], 'SELECT * FROM Table1')
```

Comment: Oh my, I am so dumb sometimes.  Yes, yes, yes, that basically worked.  I just ran this: SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY([EXCEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS], 'SELECT * FROM Table1')

Now, I get this message:
Msg 7411, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Server 'EXCEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS' is not configured for DATA ACCESS.

Comment: Actually, I think it is happening because Access is 32-bit and SQL Server is 64-bit.  I think that is the issue.  The link below should help to resolve the issue.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13255